# Installing a program with setup.exe including multiple msi-files using C# process from a subfolder

Tags: c#, wpf, process

In my `C#` `WPF` application I want to install an other program. The other program consists of a setup.exe, multiple msi files and a vcredist.exe. I need to start the setup.exe because it hands over some parameters and information to the msi files and uses an update functionality for the existing version of the program. So I can't start the msi files directly.

```
programPath = programPath + @"\setup.exe";
Process programsetup = Process.Start(programPath);
programsetup.WaitForExit();
```

Files are stored in root directory of my `C#` app. My problem is that I can't move the files to an subfolder because the msi files are always searched in the root directory and not in the subfolder.

now:

- ..\myApp\setup.exe
- ..\myApp\client.msi
- ..\myApp\host.msi
- ..\myApp\manager.msi
- ..\myApp\vcredist.exe

My question: How can I move setup.exe and msi files in a subfolder and start it from there?

What I want:

- ..\myApp\toolkit\setup.exe
- ..\myApp\toolkit\client.msi
- ..\myApp\toolkit\host.msi
- ..\myApp\toolkit\manager.msi
- ..\myApp\toolkit\vcredist.exe

Error I get during setup when I do it this way: `..\myApp\client.msi not found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.

Problem/Solution: If you start a setup file with `Process` which loads during installation some msi files from same directory you need to set `WorkingDirectory`.

Code example:

```
string ToolkitExe = myAppPath + @"\myApp\toolkit\setup.exe";
string ToolkitPath = myAppPath + @"\myApp\toolkit\";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(myAppPath + @"\myApp\toolkit\");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = myAppPath;
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
p.WaitForExit();
RunAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will directly launch setup.exe.

Properties -> right click Open to Resources.resx -> Top Left Add Existing File -> select the file.

```
byte[] resourceFile = Properties.Resources.setup;
        string destination = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "setup.exe");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destination, resourceFile);
        Process.Start(destination);
```

Comment: The above code takes the file path directly. If you do not change the path of the attached file, you should not get such an error. I tried it and it works fine for me.

Comment: You have to do it separately for each .exe or .msi. This is true for a single example.

Comment: Also when the setup.exe loads itself the msi files? Or do you mean starting every msi files with a seperate process?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean. With the above code, you can run each .msi file separately. It is not valid for batch run.

Comment: I can not run the msi files separately. They're loaded by the setup.exe.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the right way, but you can try this. When you run Setup.exe, write down the .msi files it generates and run them separately from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works with `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.